# Massachusetts State Tax: Can one at the same time apply a FICA deduction on the state tax return and ask for a FICA refund?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, state-income-tax, massachusetts

I am J1 nonresident for tax purposes using the Sprintax software and I ran into a bit of a conundrum. The software is applying a FICA deduction for my MA state tax return but I am claiming a refund of said FICA from my employer... In this situation does the FICA deduction still apply or is it a bug in the software?

Comment: How quickly do you expect to get the FICA tax refunded? Will your employer be issuing you a corrected W-2?

Comment: Not before the tax deadline. They will be issuing a W-2C but their NRA office told me to proceed with filing the return with my original W-2. Can I just add the FICA refund as income for the 2023 MA state tax return?

Answer (score 1):

Because you know you will be getting a corrected W-2, I would recommend waiting to file your actual return to both the IRS and the state and instead file the request for an extension to both agencies.

This will put your new filing deadline out to October, but it does not move the payment deadline. So what you need to do is calculate your tax returns based on the numbers you believe the corrected W-2 will show. If you are expecting a refund, then there is no problem, but if you are expecting to owe any tax, you’ll need to send that payment in along with your extension request form.

Then when your corrected W-2 arrives, you can doublecheck the numbers and file your tax returns with the right numbers. This is easier, in my opinion than filing now with numbers you know are incorrect and amending later.